# Поиск элементов с одинаковым текстом на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько блоков с содержимым(таблицы сравнения) на div'ах
Нужно найти все строки с одинаковым содержимым и спрятать их
Нашел такой вариант, но он оставляет первое из повторений

```
var find = {};
$('.row').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (find[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        find[txt] = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
var find = {};

$('.row').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  find[txt] = ~~find[txt] + 1;
}).filter(function(i, el) {
  return find[$(el).text()] > 1;
}).remove();
```

Кстати, вместо `{}` лучше использовать `Object.create(null)` если есть такая возможность.